# How to get properties in LINQ after group by clause?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing one linq query with group by clause. I am unable to retrieve the properties from one table. 
My uploadTable structure is as follows

```
    upld_docid  upld_clientid  upld_employeeid
    1002        1008           1111

    My UploadLogTable

        upld_docid      Label          value          Commited  UpdatedBy
        1002            Docnumber      123            False     Niranjan
        1002            ExpiryDate     01/01/2017     False     Niranjan
        1002            Docnumber      456            True      Azeeza
        1002            ExpiryDate     01/01/2019     True      Azeeza

    I am expecting output as

   upld_clientid  upld_employeeid  Lable        oldvalue    newValue   UpdatedBy
    1008           1111             Docnumber    123         456        Azeeza
    1008           1111             ExpiryDate   01/01/2017  01/01/2019 Azeeza
```

I have written Linq query and i am getting all the fields expect updatedby field because I am grouping everything but Updatedby field contains different values.

```
var logDetails = (from c in db.ts_upldlog_content
                  join tbl in db.ts_upld_doc on c.upld_docid equals tbl.upld_docid
                  join doc in db.tm_doc_type on tbl.upld_doctypeid equals doc.doc_typeid
                  where (c.commited == false || c.commited == true)
                     && (tbl.upld_clientid == clientId || tbl.upld_employeeid == employeeID || tbl.upld_empcitizenid == citizenId)
                  group c by new { c.upld_docid, c.upld_contentlabel, tbl.upld_clientname,tbl.upld_clientid,tbl.upld_employeeid} into grouping
                  select new logDetails
                  {
                      CId=grouping.Key.upld_clientid.Value,
                      employeeID=grouping.Key.upld_employeeid,
                      contentLabel = grouping.Key.upld_contentlabel,
                      upld_id = grouping.Key.upld_docid,
                      UpdatedBy=?  //Here I am not sure how to get updatedby
                      oldValue = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.commited == false).upld_contentvalue,
                      newValue = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.commited == true).upld_contentvalue,
                  });
return logDetails.ToList();
```

May I know how to get UpdatedBy property in the above query? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `let` keyword, before the `select` and after the `group by` to create a variable containing the record relevant for the `new data` and for the `old data`:

```
var logDetails = (from c in db.ts_upldlog_content
                  join tbl in db.ts_upld_doc on c.upld_docid equals tbl.upld_doci
                  join doc in db.tm_doc_type on tbl.upld_doctypeid equals doc.doc_typeid
                  where (c.commited == false || c.commited == true) &&
                        (tbl.upld_clientid == clientId || tbl.upld_employeeid == employeeID || tbl.upld_empcitizenid == citizenId)
                  group c by new { c.upld_docid, c.upld_contentlabel, tbl.upld_clientname,tbl.upld_clientid,tbl.upld_employeeid } into grouping

                  let OldValue = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.commited == false)
                  let NewValue = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.commited == true)

                      select new logDetails
                      {
                          CId=grouping.Key.upld_clientid.Value,
                          employeeID=grouping.Key.upld_employeeid,
                          contentLabel = grouping.Key.upld_contentlabel,
                          upld_id = grouping.Key.upld_docid,
                          UpdatedBy = NewValue.updated_by
                          oldValue = OldValue.upld_contentvalue,
                          newValue = NewValue.upld_contentvalue,
                      }).ToList();
```

Another way, if your data can contain, for your group-by columns only 1 record of `commited` that equals to `true` and 1 to `false`, and you have all the indexes defined propertly will be to select the one "type" of records (the ones with `commited == true`) and then join with the other "type".

```
var upld_content_view = from c in db.ts_upldlog_content
                        join tbl in db.ts_upld_doc on c.upld_docid equals tbl.upld_docid
                        join doc in db.tm_doc_type on tbl.upld_doctypeid equals doc.doc_typeid
                        select new { c, tbl, doc };

var result = (from u1 in upld_content_view
              where u1.commited == true &&
                    (tbl.upld_clientid == clientId || tbl.upld_employeeid == employeeID || tbl.upld_empcitizenid == citizenId)
              join u2 in upld_content_view.Where(item => item.commited == false)
              on new { u1.upld_docid, u1.upld_contentlabel }    equals  new { u2.upld_docid, u2.upld_contentlabel }  
              select new logDetails
              {
                 CId = u1.upld_clientid.Value,
                 employeeID = u1.upld_employeeid,
                 contentLabel = u1..upld_contentlabel,
                 upld_id = u1.upld_docid,
                 UpdatedBy = u1.updated_by // u1 represents the data of the NewValue
                 oldValue = u2.upld_contentvalue,
                 newValue = u1.upld_contentvalue,
              }).ToList();
```

This way you know exacly that the record of `u1` represents the shared data and the data you want that is associated with the `NewValue` while `u2` is for the data associated with the `OldValue`.

*If the assumption of the second way is correct then both ways should be tested for performance and to check what is the generated sql + the database's execution plan.*

Comment: Worked like charm. Ii want to study LINQ once i get free time. Thank you for your tutorials. Its really helpfull.